# Odoo: Opensource tool to convert .CSV files to .PO file

Tags: python-2.7, csv, converters, odoo-8, po

Is there any opensource tool which will converts .CSV file to .PO file.

If not tool, any code written in Python to convert .CSV to .PO file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [csv2po](http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/translate-toolkit/en/latest/commands/csv2po.html) which is meant for exactly this task. It is part of the  [Translate Toolkit](https://github.com/translate/translate) which you can download for your appropriate platform.